# Workmanager periodic task executed when I reopen app after frequency duration

Tags: flutter, dart

Workmanager periodic task is not executed after frequency duration. whereas it executed after restart app. and because it start after tap on app for opening so app loading take time. because in background task running.

I am just expecting workmanager periodic task execute in frequency duration with open app means normal execution.
I am using just three callbacks -
First is path provider for : get application documents directory.
Second is Shared Preference.
Third is Wallpaper Manager for changing wallpaper.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.